# C# Bitmap and Graphic, memory issues and storing screenshots in memory

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi

To start off with, to give a clear picture.

On top of my class I have:

```cs
Color FocusArea;
Bitmap FocusImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
```

and a small function to make screenshots

```cs
private void Screenshot()
{
    Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
    g.CopyFromScreen(startscanx, startscany, 0, 0, scanarea, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    g.Dispose();
    FocusImage = screenshot;
    //screenshot.Dispose(); // Shit happens when Disposing this one, wtf ?
}
```

After a minute or so (+- 3 to 6 screenshots per second) the memory has build up to around 4 to 10gb and crashes obviously.

the line it points out when crashing is :

```cs
Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
```

I tried to dispose it after putting screenshot in `FocusImage`, but then it crashes right away when using `ForusImage` in my application, I guess I am doing something horrible wrong here, I just cannot figure out what yet, I hope you can help me pointing out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If `FocusImage` is a field in your class, then a) you probably don't want to initialize it to a `new Bitmap`, and b) you certainly should `Dispose` it *before* assigning `screenshot` to it.

Comment: Do try to be more precise: Instead of tallking about 'crashing' tell us the exact error message and the line the causes it along with the error stack! Where exactly are you storing all those images?

Comment: FocusImage.Dispose();

FocusImage = screenshot;

Seems todo the trick, sadly I cannot fully test it right now since bedtime, but ill stress test it tomorrow when im back from work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from a comment of GSerg.

Before reassigning the value to FocusImage i had to Dispose it first, this seems to fix the issue, memory is nice and stable at a fixed value.

[Edit] Because someone was so triggered to downvote my question, i got the feeling i know who and why, so here is the response to it:

There were no error messages, it crashed and that was it.
0 information from visual studio in this regard, i am assuming it was because i ran out of memory at that stage.